# Can two images in the same folder have same filename but different metadata?

Tags: ftp, sftp

I have ftp server where images from different cameras are uploaded. And, i have named the images based on current time , so there might be situation where two images name might coincide.But, those two images will have different metadata.So,can i store them inside same folder ?

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two files with the same name in the same folder. You would either have to add a random string to the end of each file.

You can Either:

1. Create different folders for Different Cameras
2. Give  the name of the Camera in the file name like {Camera_Name}{Name of The File}
3. Or, Just Use Filename(1), Filename(2), But the fact is if someone wants to see the FTP server they wouldn't Understand the Difference,

Easiest Way, to do it would be, Different Folders for different Cameras ,Having the camera name in the file name is recommended as it would be easy for anyone else to understand. or, Else the System will default to Filename and Filename(2), Which No one would Understand without checking the Metadata. The System will search for the file using the path to the file, like C:/Users/User/FILE.jpg, That's why no file has the same path and Filename, Although different Extensions might have been used for the same filename, like FILE.jpg and FILE.gif, as the extension is the part of the file name.